# Remove Empty String array from ArrayList

Tags: java, strings, array

I am trying to remove empty a `String` array from `ArrayList`:

```
  List<String[]> someList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

which contains data like:

```
[
  { "Loic" , "Remy" , "Fail","Medical"} ,
  { "Faser" , "Foster" , "Pass","Southampton","GK","Young"} ,
  { "" , "" ,} ,
  { "" , "" , "","","",""} ,
  { "Emre" , "Can" , "Pass","Liverpool","CDM"}
]
```

I want to remove the empty `String[]` from the `ArrayList`:

```
List<String[]> someList = (List<String[]>) csvMappedData.get(Constants.CSV_DATA);
    //Clone to new Array List
    List<String[]> cloneCSV = new ArrayList<String[]>(someList);
    for (String[] csvSingleLine : cloneCSV) {
        //Create New List of String only
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(csvSingleLine));
        //Remove all string that are null or blank
        strings.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null, ""));
        //Check if the List is empty or null after removing in above step
        if (strings.isEmpty() || Validator.isNull(strings)) {
            //If yes it is all blank String array 
            //Remove from orginal LIST
            someList.remove(csvSingleLine);
        }
    }
```

The above code is working fine for me.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any other alternative solution that is quick and elegant?
2. What are the change that I could make to it, to make it more
   efficient?

The size of each row varies, so I couldn't use remove all by creating a dummy array.

Comment: I'd like to mention, that the excessive commenting actually makes this less readable.

Comment: Yes, in my development environment, i don't use comments that often....except for the javadoc. But i commented it out here so , i can elaborate what i have done in the code.

Comment: @Runcorn We can always see *what* you are doing, the code will tell us that. Your comments should explain *why* you are doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can use to improve this code.

First of all,

```
List<String[]> someList = (List<String[]>) csvMappedData.get(Constants.CSV_DATA);
List<String[]> cloneCSV = new ArrayList<String[]>(someList);
for (String[] csvSingleLine : cloneCSV) {
```

I understand that you're using this "copy the list"-approach to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but instead of doing that you can use an `Iterator`.

```
List<String[]> someList = (List<String[]>) csvMappedData.get(Constants.CSV_DATA);
Iterator<String[]> iterator = someList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String[] strings = iterator.next();
    if (stringsShouldBeRemoved) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

---

Now, as for your code to check for whether to remove a `String[]`:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(csvSingleLine));
strings.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null, ""));
if (strings.isEmpty() || Validator.isNull(strings)) {
    someList.remove(csvSingleLine);
}
```

Again, you're using a copying-approach. *To check for whether or not an object fulfills a criteria, you don't need to copy it, modify it, and check if it fulfills another criteria.* Copying it and modifying it makes it slower and uses more memory.

Instead, let's use a method:

```
boolean shouldRemoveCSVSingleLine(String[] csvSingleLine) {
    for (String str : csvSingleLine) {
        if (str != null && !str.equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can use this method in the `while(iterator.hasNext())` loop:

```
List<String[]> someList = (List<String[]>) csvMappedData.get(Constants.CSV_DATA);
Iterator<String[]> iterator = someList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String[] strings = iterator.next();
    if (shouldRemoveCSVSingleLine(strings)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Smion , i agree with you in the most of the reasoning you stated , except for checking the empty array. `for (String str : csvSingleLine) {` , wouldn't it be better to use `csvSingleLine.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null, ""));` ?

Comment: @Runcorn That depends, if you have the data `{ "Faser", "Foster", "Pass", "", "", "Young"}` would you want it to be modified into `{ "Faser", "Foster", "Pass", "Young"}` ?

Answer (score 5):

The removal code can be done in 1 line using the Java 8 Stream API, though I'm sure Simon's answer has better performance.

```
static List<String[]> removeEmptyStringArrays(List<String[]> strArrays) {
    return strArrays
            .stream()
            .filter(strArray -> !isEmptyStringArray(strArray))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static boolean isEmptyStringArray(String[] strArray) {
    for(String str : strArray) {
        if(str != null && !str.equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could just write `if (!"".equals(str)) { return false; }`.

Comment: Speaking of Java 8, it's even possible to do `return Arrays.stream(args).allMatch(!"".equals(str));` in the `isEmptyStringArray` method, which makes it easier to inline it inside the .filter lambda directly.

Comment: +1 @emagdne Thanks for the answer, I have not yet ported to Java 8 .. But hey i will someday .. :D